# Are licensing questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There have been a couple questions asked about licensing, with mixed responses (some were  closed, others were answered).

Examples:

- [Blender use as world editor, level editor..etc, License problem?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13892/599)
- [Must I add a license block to all files in a multi file addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/704/599)
- [Can I use images rendered with blender for commercial use?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12331/599)

Are these off-topic or not?

If not, should we resurrect the [license](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) tag?

Comment: This meta post details why having people give legal advice online is a really really bad idea.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they are, due to the legal risk they can pose to both the Stack Exchange Network,and the community members. There is a reason why legal consultants get paid as much as they do, they *cant* afford to make errors.

Comment: There's now a [law.stackexchange](http://law.stackexchange.com) and an [opensource.stackexchange](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) which appear to deal with these kinds of questions. Perhaps we can send them there